# Replacing a specified column in a list of tibbles with a list of vectors in R

Tags: r

I am exploding a data file to then run a function on components of it, and then trying to piece it back together replacing a specified variable with new values. The function is below, it is used to count the number of c's in the specific component part of a data file, and if there is only 1, then it replaces the next lowest value with another c to ensure that there are at least 2 in any single component of the data file.

```
secondary_supp <- function(x){
  if(sum(x == "c") == 1){
    replace(x, which.min(x), "c")
  }
  else{x}
}
```

At the moment I am starting off by exploding the data file using the following:

```
exploded_file <- data %>% 
  group_by(year,area,treatment_a,treatment_b) %>% 
  nest() 

# selecting the list of tibbles
components <- exploded_file[5][[1]]

# running the function on the components
measure_a_supped <- lapply(components, function(x){secondary_supp(x[['measure_a']])})
```

It is at this point I need to then replace the original values for the 'measure_a' variable for each tibble within the list, with these new 'measure_a_supped' values.

I assume that I can replace the column of tibbles in 'exploded_file' with another list of tibbles, and know then that I can unnest, and ungroup to get back to the full data file. I'm stuck at how to replace the values with the list of vectors (measure_a_supped) that I've created, to then get back to the list of tibbles to let me get back to the structure of the original data table with the updated values.

Example data if needed to run the above lines of code on:

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_data = read.table(text="year    level   area    location    treatment_a treatment_b measure_a
2015    national    NULL    NULL    Total   Total   563
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    group_a Total   370
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    group_b Total   193
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  Total   Total   119
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  group_a Total   93
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  group_b Total   26
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  Total   Total   163
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  group_a Total   92
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  group_b Total   71
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    Total   Total   282
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    group_a Total   185
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    group_b Total   97
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  Total   Total   143
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  group_a Total   88
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  group_b Total   55
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  Total   Total   138
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  group_a Total   97
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  group_b Total   41
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    Total   Total   281
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    group_a Total   185
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    group_b Total   96
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    Total   group_1 389
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    group_a group_1 295
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    group_b group_1 94
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  Total   group_1 80
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  group_a group_1 64
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  group_b group_1 16
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  Total   group_1 88
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  group_a group_1 72
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  group_b group_1 16
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    Total   group_1 168
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    group_a group_1 136
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    group_b group_1 32
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  Total   group_1 125
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  group_a group_1 75
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  group_b group_1 50
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  Total   group_1 96
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  group_a group_1 84
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  group_b group_1 12
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    Total   group_1 221
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    group_a group_1 159
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    group_b group_1 62
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    Total   group_2 426
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    group_a group_2 212
                  2015  national    NULL    NULL    group_b group_2 214
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  Total   group_2 72
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  group_a group_2 71
                  2015  location    area_a  location_a  group_b group_2 1
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  Total   group_2 135
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  group_a group_2 80
                  2015  location    area_a  location_b  group_b group_2 55
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    Total   group_2 207
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    group_a group_2 151
                  2015  area    area_a  NULL    group_b group_2 56
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  Total   group_2 125
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  group_a group_2 30
                  2015  location    area_b  location_c  group_b group_2 95
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  Total   group_2 94
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  group_a group_2 31
                  2015  location    area_b  location_d  group_b group_2 63
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    Total   group_2 219
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    group_a group_2 61
                  2015  area    area_b  NULL    group_b group_2 158
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    Total   Total   470
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    group_a Total   156
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    group_b Total   314
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  Total   Total   117
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  group_a Total   28
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  group_b Total   89
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  Total   Total   125
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  group_a Total   27
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  group_b Total   98
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    Total   Total   242
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    group_a Total   55
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    group_b Total   187
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  Total   Total   71
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  group_a Total   25
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  group_b Total   46
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  Total   Total   157
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  group_a Total   76
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  group_b Total   81
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    Total   Total   228
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    group_a Total   101
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    group_b Total   127
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    Total   group_1 502
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    group_a group_1 210
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    group_b group_1 292
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  Total   group_1 179
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  group_a group_1 84
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  group_b group_1 95
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  Total   group_1 100
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  group_a group_1 49
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  group_b group_1 51
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    Total   group_1 279
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    group_a group_1 133
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    group_b group_1 146
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  Total   group_1 107
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  group_a group_1 35
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  group_b group_1 72
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  Total   group_1 116
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  group_a group_1 42
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  group_b group_1 74
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    Total   group_1 223
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    group_a group_1 77
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    group_b group_1 146
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    Total   group_2 478
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    group_a group_2 241
                  2014  national    NULL    NULL    group_b group_2 237
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  Total   group_2 69
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  group_a group_2 56
                  2014  location    area_a  location_a  group_b group_2 13
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  Total   group_2 139
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  group_a group_2 52
                  2014  location    area_a  location_b  group_b group_2 87
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    Total   group_2 208
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    group_a group_2 108
                  2014  area    area_a  NULL    group_b group_2 100
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  Total   group_2 149
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  group_a group_2 50
                  2014  location    area_b  location_c  group_b group_2 99
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  Total   group_2 121
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  group_a group_2 83
                  2014  location    area_b  location_d  group_b group_2 38
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    Total   group_2 270
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    group_a group_2 133
                  2014  area    area_b  NULL    group_b group_2 137

                  ",header=TRUE)

data <- raw_data
data$measure_a <- replace(data[["measure_a"]],data[["measure_a"]]<40,"c")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate_if` to select which column we apply to then use `lag` to `replace` the next value of `"area_c"` with `"area_c"`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
#Create one group which includes "area_c" for testing
raw_data$area <- as.character(raw_data$area)
raw_data[1,"area"] <- "area_c"
#Use `group_split` instead of nest()
lst <- raw_data %>% group_split(year, level)

#Test with one element from lst
lst[[6]] %>% 
         mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
         mutate_if(.,~sum(grepl("c",.))==1,~replace(.,lag(.)=="area_c","c"))



#Use map_df if you need the output as df
map(lst, ~.x %>% 
             mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
             mutate_if(., ~sum(grepl("c",.))==1, ~replace(.,lag(.)=="area_c","area_c")))
```

Comment: tweaked this to the following to get it working exactly how I wanted - thank you!  <br/>
  
`lst <- data %>% group_split(year, area, treatment_a, treatment_b)
  
map_df(lst, ~.x %>% 
      mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
      mutate_if(., ~sum(grepl("c",.))==1, ~replace(.,which.min(.),"c")))`